# How do I add a variable into my color3.fromrgb value?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

```
local R = script.Parent.R.Text
local G = script.Parent.G.Text
local B = script.Parent.B.Text
script.Parent.ColorIndicator.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(R, G, B)
```

Ok, so how do I make this work? I'm making a Building Tools like thing that would let you customize the color, and I want it to work by using the Text value of a TextBox to change the color of the part that would be created, any help will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Instances come with a [GetPropertyChangedSignal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetPropertyChangedSignal) function that you can utilize to update the color anytime the text changes.

```lua
-- find the UI elements
local R = script.Parent.R
local G = script.Parent.G
local B = script.Parent.B
local Indicator = script.Parent.ColorIndicator

local function clamp(minimum, value, maximum)
    return math.max(minimum, math.min(value, maximum))
end

local function updateColor(newValue)
    -- use pcall to safely try and update the colors
    local success, result = pcall(function()
        -- try to convert the text to numbers
        local r = tonumber(R.Text) or 0
        local g = tonumber(G.Text) or 0
        local b = tonumber(B.Text) or 0
        
        -- limit numbers to a valid range
        local clampedR = clamp(0, r, 255)
        local clampedG = clamp(0, g, 255)
        local clampedB = clamp(0, b, 255)

        -- set the color
        Indicator.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(clampedR, clampedG, clampedB)
    end)
    if not success then
        warn("Failed to update colorIndicator with error : ", result)
    end
end

-- listen for changes on each of the text boxes
R:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Text"):Connect(updateColor)
G:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Text"):Connect(updateColor)
B:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Text"):Connect(updateColor)
```

There is more you could do to prevent the user from entering text that is not numbers, like checking the `newValue` string for non-numerical characters and removing them... but that seems beyond what you're asking here.

Comment: Oh also, this is assumed to be all in a LocalScript.

Comment: something went wrong....  10:38:36.388  Failed to update colorIndicator with error :  Players.0_0ohiamRDJpower.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.DevsTools.Color.ColorUI.LocalScript:12: invalid argument #1 to 'min' (number expected, got nil) (x14)  -  Client - LocalScript:32

Comment: ok that's fixed but now i have another error....   10:43:16.961  Failed to update colorIndicator with error :  Players.0_0ohiamRDJpower.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.DevsTools.Color.ColorUI.LocalScript:8: invalid argument #1 to 'min' (number expected, got nil) (x6)  -  Client - LocalScript:28

Comment: I think its because  min does not mean a number but I honestly don't know.

Comment: These errors are saying that the text from one of the text boxes is empty. I'll add another safety check.

Comment: it works! those measures worked